# Upgraded to 22.04.1 and I can't change display settings

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors

(Upgraded from 22.04) After upgrade, my desktop background was switched to default, and external monitor arrangement was changed.  I was able to set the background back, but whenever I attempt to modify the monitor arrangement the system pauses for several seconds and then the two external monitors go white-fuzzy, then I'm back at the login prompt.  (I assume the display manager crashed).

Laptop:  Dell Precision 7540, conencted to 2 external monitors, with both Intel and AMD Radeon pro wx 3200 graphics cards.  I'd guess there's something going on with the graphics cards/drivers, but I don't know enough to figure out how to fix it.  Possibly relevant messages in dmesg output:

```
[   4.195071] [drm:lspcon_init [i915]] *ERROR* Failed to probe lspcon
[   4.756003] [drm:lspcon_init [i915]] *ERROR* LSPCON init failed on port D
...
[   5.852127] [drm:dce110_edp_wait_for_hdp_ready [amdgpu]] *ERROR* dce110_edp_wait_for_hpd_ready: wait timed out!
```

The above repeats multiple times throughout dmesg output.

Comment: did this get resolved ? ... I'm on 22.04 with an nvidia card with one external monitor ... I see your above error messages in dmesg yet my displays are all OK

Comment: @ScottStensland no, it still does this, but the displays suddenly started working at some point.